# How to convert Iterator to scalaz stream?

Tags: scala, scalaz-stream

Suppose I've got an `Iterator[A]`. I would like to convert it to `Process[Nothing, A]` of [scalaz stream](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream).

```
import scalaz.stream._

def foo[A](it: Iterator[A]): Process[Nothing, A] = ???
```

How would you implement `foo` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that you can do it using `unfold`:

```
import scalaz.stream._

def foo[A](it: Iterator[A]): Process[Nothing, A] = Process.unfold(it) { it =>
  if (it.hasNext) Some((it.next, it))
  else None
}
```

Example:

```
scala> foo(List(1,2,3,4,5).iterator).toList
res0: List[Int] = List(1,2,3,4,5)
```